# Which is faster, InnoDB or MyISAM?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam, storage-engine

How can MyISAM be "faster" than InnoDB if

- MyISAM needs to do disk reads for the data?
- InnoDB uses the buffer pool for indexes and data, and MyISAM just for the index?

Comment: MyISAM lets the OS cache _data_ blocks, so it does _not_ always "do disk reads for the data".

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The only way MyISAM can be faster that InnoDB would be under this unique circumstance

## **MyISAM**

When read, a MyISAM table's indexes can be read once from the .MYI file and loaded in the MyISAM Key Cache (as sized by [**key_buffer_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_key_buffer_size)). How can you make a MyISAM table's .MYD faster to read? With this:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ROW_FORMAT=Fixed;
```

I wrote about this in my past posts

- [Best of MyISAM and InnoDB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5974/best-of-myisam-and-innodb/6008#6008) (Please Read This One First)
- [What is the performance impact of using CHAR vs VARCHAR on a fixed-size field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2640/what-is-the-performance-impact-of-using-char-vs-varchar-on-a-fixed-size-field/2643#2643) (TRADEOFF #2)
- [Optimized my.cnf for high-end and busy server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10069/optimized-my-cnf-for-high-end-and-busy-server/10080#10080) (Under the heading **Replication**)
- [Which DBMS is good for super-fast reads and a simple data structure?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4576/which-dbms-is-good-for-super-fast-reads-and-a-simple-data-structure/4589#4589) (Paragraph 3)

## **InnoDB**

OK, what about InnoDB? Does InnoDB do any disk I/O for queries? Surprisingly, yes it does !! You are probably thinking I am crazy for saying that, but it is absolutely true, **even for SELECT queries**. At this point, you are probably wondering "How in the world is InnoDB doing disk I/O for queries?"

It all goes back to InnoDB being an [**ACID**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)-complaint Transactional Storage Engine. In order for InnoDB to be Transactional, it has to support the `I` in `ACID`, which is Isolation. The technique for maintaining isolation for transactions is done via [**MVCC, Multiversion Concurrency Control**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control). In simple terms, InnoDB records what data looks like before transactions attempt to change them. Where does that get recorded? In the system tablespace file, better known as ibdata1. **That requires disk I/O**.

## **COMPARISON**

Since both InnoDB and MyISAM do disk I/O, what random factors dictate who is faster?

- Size of Columns
- Column Format
- Character Sets
- Range of Numeric Values (requiring large enough INTs)
- Rows Being Split Across Blocks (Row Chaining)
- Data Fragmentation caused by `DELETEs` and `UPDATEs`
- Size of Primary Key (InnoDB has a Clustered Index, requiring two key lookups)
- Size of Index Entries
- the list goes on...

Thus, in a heavy-read environment, it is possible for a MyISAM table with a Fixed Row Format to outperform InnoDB reads out of the InnoDB Buffer Pool if there is enough data being written into the undo logs contained within ibdata1 to support the transactional behavior imposed on the InnoDB data.

## **CONCLUSION**

Plan your data types, queries, and storage engine real carefully. Once the data grows, it might become very difficult to move data around. [*Just ask Facebook...*](http://gigaom.com/cloud/facebook-trapped-in-mysql-fate-worse-than-death/)

Comment: Excellent answer, Rolando.  I have to question your inclusion of the incredulous claims made by Michael Stonebreaker, who is simply trying to sell his own product and knows nothing about Facebook.  Having listened to Facebook present about MySQL several times, it is clear that they are comfortable with their choices.

Comment: @AaronBrown I have listened to Harrison Fisk last year at Percona Live NYC and you are right -- Facebook  is very happy with their exclusive use of InnoDB and how they spend time coming up with ways to do online schema change system wide. He even offer the audience the chance to work for Facebook handling big data. I included the article to show that some have fears about that. I would welcome the chance to work with huge data. It would be fun and challenging. Imagine the techniques there are to learn. Of course, I would never touch MyISAM for the rest of my life...

Comment: I was also at that conference (and had the good fortune to be able to give a talk) & Harrison's presentation was excellent.

Answer (score 24):

In a simple world, MyISAM is faster for reads, InnoDB is faster for writes.

Once you start introducing mixed read/writes, InnoDB will be faster for reads as well, thanks to its Row locking mechanism.

I wrote a comparison of 
[MySQL storage engines](http://www.softwareprojects.com/resources/programming/t-mysql-storage-engines-1470.html) a few years ago, that still holds true to this day, outlining the unique differences between MyISAM and InnoDB.

In my experience, you should use InnoDB for everything except for read-heavy cache-tables, where losing data due to corruption is not as critical.

Comment: _This Answer is 5 years out of date._  InnoDB has caught up in virtually all ways; there is no longer much argument for using MyISAM.  MySQL 8.0 is in the process of _removing_ MyISAM all together.

Comment: And the link is now 9 years out of date.

Comment: Correction, the answer is 9 years out of date (anybody reading the first sentence will have some serious problems when doing their Database) and the link is 11 years out of date. Catch up Rick James, you are falling behind :).

Comment: You're right @CYREX :-) Its amazing this post is still getting traffic, 11 years later.  So much has changed both in my life and in the way InnoDB is optimized.  Nowadays, there's rarely ever a justification to use MyISAM

Comment: I had to look at some dying databases today and both engines still in use with old version of mysql. Tables are both InnoDB and MyISAM and my curiosity brought me to this post which was very helpful.

Answer (score 19):

To add to the responses here covering the mechanical differences between the two engines, I present an empirical speed comparison study.

In terms of pure speed, it is not always the case that MyISAM is faster than InnoDB but in my experience it tends to be faster for PURE READ working environments by a factor of about 2.0-2.5 times. Clearly this isn't appropriate for all environments - as others have written, MyISAM lacks such things as transactions and foreign keys.

I've done a bit of benchmarking below - I've used python for looping and the timeit library for timing comparisons. For interest I've also included the memory engine, this gives the best performance across the board although it is only suitable for smaller tables (you continually encounter `The table 'tbl' is full` when you exceed the MySQL memory limit). The four types of select I look at are:

1. vanilla SELECTs
2. counts
3. conditional SELECTs
4. indexed and non-indexed sub-selects

Firstly, I created three tables using the following SQL

```
CREATE TABLE
    data_interrogation.test_table_myisam
    (
        index_col BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        value1 DOUBLE,
        value2 DOUBLE,
        value3 DOUBLE,
        value4 DOUBLE,
        PRIMARY KEY (index_col)
    )
    ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

with 'MyISAM' substituted for 'InnoDB' and 'memory' in the second and third tables.

## 1) Vanilla selects

Query: `SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE index_col = xx`

Result: **draw**

[image: Comparison of vanilla selects by different database engines]

The speed of these is all broadly the same, and as expected is linear in the number of columns to be selected. InnoDB seems *slightly* faster than MyISAM but this is really marginal.

Code:

```
import timeit
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors
import random
from random import randint

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="...", user="...", passwd="...", db="...", cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
cur = db.cursor()

lengthOfTable = 100000

# Fill up the tables with random data
for x in xrange(lengthOfTable):
    rand1 = random.random()
    rand2 = random.random()
    rand3 = random.random()
    rand4 = random.random()

    insertString = "INSERT INTO test_table_innodb (value1,value2,value3,value4) VALUES (" + str(rand1) + "," + str(rand2) + "," + str(rand3) + "," + str(rand4) + ")"
    insertString2 = "INSERT INTO test_table_myisam (value1,value2,value3,value4) VALUES (" + str(rand1) + "," + str(rand2) + "," + str(rand3) + "," + str(rand4) + ")"
    insertString3 = "INSERT INTO test_table_memory (value1,value2,value3,value4) VALUES (" + str(rand1) + "," + str(rand2) + "," + str(rand3) + "," + str(rand4) + ")"

    cur.execute(insertString)
    cur.execute(insertString2)
    cur.execute(insertString3)

db.commit()

# Define a function to pull a certain number of records from these tables
def selectRandomRecords(testTable,numberOfRecords):

    for x in xrange(numberOfRecords):
        rand1 = randint(0,lengthOfTable)

        selectString = "SELECT * FROM " + testTable + " WHERE index_col = " + str(rand1)
        cur.execute(selectString)

setupString = "from __main__ import selectRandomRecords"

# Test time taken using timeit
myisam_times = []
innodb_times = []
memory_times = []

for theLength in [3,10,30,100,300,1000,3000,10000]:

    innodb_times.append( timeit.timeit('selectRandomRecords("test_table_innodb",' + str(theLength) + ')', number=100, setup=setupString) )
    myisam_times.append( timeit.timeit('selectRandomRecords("test_table_myisam",' + str(theLength) + ')', number=100, setup=setupString) )
    memory_times.append( timeit.timeit('selectRandomRecords("test_table_memory",' + str(theLength) + ')', number=100, setup=setupString) )
```

## 2) Counts

Query: `SELECT count(*) FROM tbl`

Result: **MyISAM wins**

[image: Comparison of counts by different database engines]

This one demonstrates a big difference between MyISAM and InnoDB - MyISAM (and memory) keeps track of the number of records in the table, so this transaction is fast and O(1). The amount of time required for InnoDB to count increases super-linearly with table size in the range I investigated. I suspect many of the speed-ups from MyISAM queries that are observed in practice are due to similar effects.

Code:

```
myisam_times = []
innodb_times = []
memory_times = []

# Define a function to count the records
def countRecords(testTable):

    selectString = "SELECT count(*) FROM " + testTable
    cur.execute(selectString)

setupString = "from __main__ import countRecords"

# Truncate the tables and re-fill with a set amount of data
for theLength in [3,10,30,100,300,1000,3000,10000,30000,100000]:

    truncateString = "TRUNCATE test_table_innodb"
    truncateString2 = "TRUNCATE test_table_myisam"
    truncateString3 = "TRUNCATE test_table_memory"

    cur.execute(truncateString)
    cur.execute(truncateString2)
    cur.execute(truncateString3)

    for x in xrange(theLength):
        rand1 = random.random()
        rand2 = random.random()
        rand3 = random.random()
        rand4 = random.random()

        insertString = "INSERT INTO test_table_innodb (value1,value2,value3,value4) VALUES (" + str(rand1) + "," + str(rand2) + "," + str(rand3) + "," + str(rand4) + ")"
        insertString2 = "INSERT INTO test_table_myisam (value1,value2,value3,value4) VALUES (" + str(rand1) + "," + str(rand2) + "," + str(rand3) + "," + str(rand4) + ")"
        insertString3 = "INSERT INTO test_table_memory (value1,value2,value3,value4) VALUES (" + str(rand1) + "," + str(rand2) + "," + str(rand3) + "," + str(rand4) + ")"

        cur.execute(insertString)
        cur.execute(insertString2)
        cur.execute(insertString3)

    db.commit()

    # Count and time the query
    innodb_times.append( timeit.timeit('countRecords("test_table_innodb")', number=100, setup=setupString) )
    myisam_times.append( timeit.timeit('countRecords("test_table_myisam")', number=100, setup=setupString) )
    memory_times.append( timeit.timeit('countRecords("test_table_memory")', number=100, setup=setupString) )
```

## 3) Conditional selects

Query: `SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE value1<0.5 AND value2<0.5 AND value3<0.5 AND value4<0.5`

Result: **MyISAM wins**

[image: Comparison of conditional selects by different database engines]

Here, MyISAM and memory perform approximately the same, and beat InnoDB by about 50% for larger tables. This is the sort of query for which the benefits of MyISAM seem to be maximised.

Code:

```
myisam_times = []
innodb_times = []
memory_times = []

# Define a function to perform conditional selects
def conditionalSelect(testTable):
    selectString = "SELECT * FROM " + testTable + " WHERE value1 < 0.5 AND value2 < 0.5 AND value3 < 0.5 AND value4 < 0.5"
    cur.execute(selectString)

setupString = "from __main__ import conditionalSelect"

# Truncate the tables and re-fill with a set amount of data
for theLength in [3,10,30,100,300,1000,3000,10000,30000,100000]:

    truncateString = "TRUNCATE test_table_innodb"
    truncateString2 = "TRUNCATE test_table_myisam"
    truncateString3 = "TRUNCATE test_table_memory"

    cur.execute(truncateString)
    cur.execute(truncateString2)
    cur.execute(truncateString3)

    for x in xrange(theLength):
        rand1 = random.random()
        rand2 = random.random()
        rand3 = random.random()
        rand4 = random.random()

        insertString = "INSERT INTO test_table_innodb (value1,value2,value3,value4) VALUES (" + str(rand1) + "," + str(rand2) + "," + str(rand3) + "," + str(rand4) + ")"
        insertString2 = "INSERT INTO test_table_myisam (value1,value2,value3,value4) VALUES (" + str(rand1) + "," + str(rand2) + "," + str(rand3) + "," + str(rand4) + ")"
        insertString3 = "INSERT INTO test_table_memory (value1,value2,value3,value4) VALUES (" + str(rand1) + "," + str(rand2) + "," + str(rand3) + "," + str(rand4) + ")"

        cur.execute(insertString)
        cur.execute(insertString2)
        cur.execute(insertString3)

    db.commit()

    # Count and time the query
    innodb_times.append( timeit.timeit('conditionalSelect("test_table_innodb")', number=100, setup=setupString) )
    myisam_times.append( timeit.timeit('conditionalSelect("test_table_myisam")', number=100, setup=setupString) )
    memory_times.append( timeit.timeit('conditionalSelect("test_table_memory")', number=100, setup=setupString) )
```

## 4) Sub-selects

Result: **InnoDB wins**

For this query, I created an additional set of tables for the sub-select. Each is simply two columns of BIGINTs, one with a primary key index and one without any index. Due to the large table size, I didn't test the memory engine. The SQL table creation command was

```
CREATE TABLE
    subselect_myisam
    (
        index_col bigint NOT NULL,
        non_index_col bigint,
        PRIMARY KEY (index_col)
    )
    ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

where once again, 'MyISAM' is substituted for 'InnoDB' in the second table.

In this query, I leave the size of the selection table at 1000000 and instead vary the size of the sub-selected columns.

[image: Comparison of sub-selects by different database engines]

Here the InnoDB wins easily. After we get to a reasonable size table both engines scale linearly with the size of the sub-select. The index speeds up the MyISAM command but interestingly has little effect on the InnoDB speed.
subSelect.png

Code:

```
myisam_times = []
innodb_times = []
myisam_times_2 = []
innodb_times_2 = []

def subSelectRecordsIndexed(testTable,testSubSelect):
    selectString = "SELECT * FROM " + testTable + " WHERE index_col in ( SELECT index_col FROM " + testSubSelect + " )"
    cur.execute(selectString)

setupString = "from __main__ import subSelectRecordsIndexed"

def subSelectRecordsNotIndexed(testTable,testSubSelect):
    selectString = "SELECT * FROM " + testTable + " WHERE index_col in ( SELECT non_index_col FROM " + testSubSelect + " )"
    cur.execute(selectString)

setupString2 = "from __main__ import subSelectRecordsNotIndexed"

# Truncate the old tables, and re-fill with 1000000 records
truncateString = "TRUNCATE test_table_innodb"
truncateString2 = "TRUNCATE test_table_myisam"

cur.execute(truncateString)
cur.execute(truncateString2)

lengthOfTable = 1000000

# Fill up the tables with random data
for x in xrange(lengthOfTable):
    rand1 = random.random()
    rand2 = random.random()
    rand3 = random.random()
    rand4 = random.random()

    insertString = "INSERT INTO test_table_innodb (value1,value2,value3,value4) VALUES (" + str(rand1) + "," + str(rand2) + "," + str(rand3) + "," + str(rand4) + ")"
    insertString2 = "INSERT INTO test_table_myisam (value1,value2,value3,value4) VALUES (" + str(rand1) + "," + str(rand2) + "," + str(rand3) + "," + str(rand4) + ")"

    cur.execute(insertString)
    cur.execute(insertString2)

for theLength in [3,10,30,100,300,1000,3000,10000,30000,100000]:

    truncateString = "TRUNCATE subselect_innodb"
    truncateString2 = "TRUNCATE subselect_myisam"

    cur.execute(truncateString)
    cur.execute(truncateString2)

    # For each length, empty the table and re-fill it with random data
    rand_sample = sorted(random.sample(xrange(lengthOfTable), theLength))
    rand_sample_2 = random.sample(xrange(lengthOfTable), theLength)

    for (the_value_1,the_value_2) in zip(rand_sample,rand_sample_2):
        insertString = "INSERT INTO subselect_innodb (index_col,non_index_col) VALUES (" + str(the_value_1) + "," + str(the_value_2) + ")"
        insertString2 = "INSERT INTO subselect_myisam (index_col,non_index_col) VALUES (" + str(the_value_1) + "," + str(the_value_2) + ")"

        cur.execute(insertString)
        cur.execute(insertString2)

    db.commit()

    # Finally, time the queries
    innodb_times.append( timeit.timeit('subSelectRecordsIndexed("test_table_innodb","subselect_innodb")', number=100, setup=setupString) )
    myisam_times.append( timeit.timeit('subSelectRecordsIndexed("test_table_myisam","subselect_myisam")', number=100, setup=setupString) )
        
    innodb_times_2.append( timeit.timeit('subSelectRecordsNotIndexed("test_table_innodb","subselect_innodb")', number=100, setup=setupString2) )
    myisam_times_2.append( timeit.timeit('subSelectRecordsNotIndexed("test_table_myisam","subselect_myisam")', number=100, setup=setupString2) )
```

I think the take-home message of all of this is that if you are *really* concerned about speed, you need to benchmark the queries that you're doing rather than make any assumptions about which engine will be more suitable.

Comment: I like your answer because it is in favor whoever you benchmark and decide on. No two systems benefit the same way from different storage engines and due diligence is required to choose a storage engine. +1 for you and Welcome to the DBA StackExchange !!!

Comment: Also, see my post http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-the-main-differences-between-innodb-and-myisam/2194#2194 along with the other answers. Your post kind of goes above and beyond.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE index_col = xx` -- Here are two factors that are likely to lead to more variation in the graph:  Primary key vs secondary key; index is cached vs not.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*)` is a clear winner for MyISAM until you add a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I suppose that my point is that each query needs to be benchmarked separately. I've included the code in the answer - if you want to trial a different query, please be my guest - or be explicit what query you want and I'll add it.

Answer (score 4):

Which is faster?  Either might be faster.  YMMV.

Which should you use?  InnoDB -- crash-safe, etc, etc.

Comment: please, define "etc, etc."

Comment: @dellasavia - The most recent "etc" is that Oracle is planning to remove MyISAM.  They are that confident in InnoDB.