# MySQL Read Speed and Partitioning on Separate Drives

Tags: mysql, performance, partitioning, myisam, mysql-5.6

## Introduction

Simple project but for an heavy read load -90% reads- over a table(~20Milion Rows ever-growing where I have to boost performance and ensure response low time for read queries) that was partitioned for a fixed field -21 partitions, avg 1Mln Row/Partition- like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table`  (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `fieldA` char(40) NOT NULL,
 `fieldB` char(40) NOT NULL,
 `fieldC` char(32) DEFAULT NULL,
 -- some other fields
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`fieldC`)
 -- some other index
) ENGINE=MyISAM 
PARTITION BY LIST COLUMNS(`fieldC`) (
  partition pNULLorEMPTY VALUES IN(NULL,''),
  partition pValueA VALUES IN('valueA'),
  partition pValueB VALUES IN('valueB'),
  partition pValueC VALUES IN('valueC')
  -- other partitions
);
```

The root of the queries are always "`WHERE fieldC = ? ... AND ...`" so I always guaranteed access to a partition.

This table can be only MyISAM so I have installed the MySQL server 5.6.11

> Prior to MySQL 5.6.6, a SELECT from a partitioned MyISAM table caused
>   a lock on the entire table;  in MySQL 5.6.6 and later, only those
>   partitions actually containing rows that satisfy the  SELECT
>   statement's WHERE condition are locked. This has the effect of
>   increasing the speed  and efficiency of concurrent operations on
>   partitioned MyISAM tables.

The setup consist on a Master/Slave topology with same HW (I can distribuite reads across Master and Slave)

## Possible solution

I have tree choice for the hardware architecture(6 slot disk 3.5''):

### Soloution #1

- 1xraid1 for OS, /tmp and binlog
- 1xraid1 partition for mysql data (ex: /diskA)
- 1xraid1 additional partition for mysql data (ex: /diskB)

### Soloution #2

- 1xraid1 OS, /tmp and binlog
- 1xraid10 mysql data

### Soloution #3 (2 disk waste for tmp!)

- 1xraid1 OS and binlog
- 1xraid1 partition for mysql data
- 1xraid1 /tmp

The first choice can help me to spread the I/O over two disk using the:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table`  (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `fieldA` char(40) NOT NULL,
 `fieldB` char(40) NOT NULL,
 `fieldC` char(32) DEFAULT NULL,
 -- some other fields
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`fieldC`)
 -- some other index
) ENGINE=MyISAM 
PARTITION BY LIST COLUMNS(`fieldC`) (
  partition pNULLorEMPTY VALUES IN(NULL,'')
    DATA DIRECTORY = '/diskA/customer' 
    INDEX DIRECTORY = '/diskA/customer',
  partition pValueA VALUES IN('valueA')
    DATA DIRECTORY = '/diskB/customer' 
    INDEX DIRECTORY = '/diskB/customer',
  partition pValueB VALUES IN('valueB')
    DATA DIRECTORY = '/diskA/customer' 
    INDEX DIRECTORY = '/diskA/customer',
  partition pValueC VALUES IN('valueC')
    DATA DIRECTORY = '/diskB/customer' 
    INDEX DIRECTORY = '/diskB/customer'
  -- other partitions
);
```

The second choice improve the fault tolerance level, but consider that I have a Master/Slave configuration so, in every moment, I can promote the Slave as a Master.

What kind of architecture you advice?

There are problems that at the moment I do not see?

Any other kind of suggestions would be greatly appreciated. :)

Thanks in advance

crx

Answer (score 1):

What concerns me fact that `fieldC` is not the lead column in the `PRIMARY KEY`.

What would be preferable is to reverse the order to the primary key columns

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table`  (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `fieldA` char(40) NOT NULL,
 `fieldB` char(40) NOT NULL,
 `fieldC` char(32) DEFAULT NULL,
 -- some other fields
 PRIMARY KEY (`fieldC`,`id`)
 -- some other index
) ENGINE=MyISAM 
PARTITION BY LIST COLUMNS(`fieldC`) (
  partition pNULLorEMPTY VALUES IN(NULL,''),
  partition pValueA VALUES IN('valueA'),
  partition pValueB VALUES IN('valueB'),
  partition pValueC VALUES IN('valueC')
  -- other partitions
);
```

This may help navigate faster through the partitions. The MySQL Query Optimizer may/may not be smart enough to need the reversal.

If you have other columns in the WHERE clauses such as

- `WHERE fieldC='...' AND fieldA='...'`
- `WHERE fieldC='...' AND fieldB='...'`

you will need matching indexes so quickly search within one partition. Otherwise, you may find yourself doing a full table scan with the partition.

With that in mind, please create the table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table`  (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `fieldA` char(40) NOT NULL,
 `fieldB` char(40) NOT NULL,
 `fieldC` char(32) DEFAULT NULL,
 -- some other fields
 PRIMARY KEY (`fieldC`,`id`),
 KEY C_A_Index (`fieldC`,`fieldA`),
 KEY C_B_Index (`fieldC`,`fieldB`)
 -- some other index
) ENGINE=MyISAM 
PARTITION BY LIST COLUMNS(`fieldC`) (
  partition pNULLorEMPTY VALUES IN(NULL,''),
  partition pValueA VALUES IN('valueA'),
  partition pValueB VALUES IN('valueB'),
  partition pValueC VALUES IN('valueC')
  -- other partitions
);
```

This will then accommodate such WHERE clauses.

Give it a Try !!!

## CAVEAT

I noticed your character fields are `CHAR` and not `VARCHAR`. That's great.

If any of the character fields are `VARCHAR`, please read on.

If there are any `VARCHAR` fields, you need not convert them manually. Simply change the row storage format as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ROW_FORMAT=Fixed;
```

This will make the table's read speed increase 20%-25%. I wrote about this before:

- `May 10, 2011` : [What is the performance impact of using CHAR vs VARCHAR on a fixed-size field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2640/what-is-the-performance-impact-of-using-char-vs-varchar-on-a-fixed-size-field/2643#2643)
- `Aug 12, 2011` : [Which DBMS is good for super-fast reads and a simple data structure?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4576/which-dbms-is-good-for-super-fast-reads-and-a-simple-data-structure/4589#4589)
- `Sep 20, 2011` : [Best of MyISAM and InnoDB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5974/best-of-myisam-and-innodb/6008#6008-) `Jan 03, 2012` : [Optimized my.cnf for high-end and busy server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10069/optimized-my-cnf-for-high-end-and-busy-server/10080#10080)

Comment: thank you for your response! Changing the order of the primary key appers a good solution. Yes, the table are fully ROW_FORMAT=Fixed. Wath do you think about the raid choice and about "spreading" data on differents drive ?