# mysql - is it possible to create a partition expression based on two keys / indexes?

Tags: mysql, partitioning

if i have a table with, lets say 500 million rows, and among others there are two main individual indexes on that table. the table looks like:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `t1` (
>     id_1 bigint unsigned not null,
>     id_2 bigint unsigned not null,
>     col3, col4 ... colN ...
>     KEY `index1` (`id_1`),
>     KEY `index2` (`id_2`),
>     ...
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
> ```

100% of the queries on the table are using **WHERE** clause on index1 OR index2.

Taking this into account, and assuming it is now very reasonable time to partition that table, into 100 partitions, I would like to ask your help to understand these issues:

1. Is it possible to create a partition expression in such a way that after the partitioning, for any query that using one of these indexes:

   > ```
   > SELECT * FROM `t1` WHERE id_1 = 123;
   > -- or
   > SELECT * FROM `t1` WHERE id_2 = 456;
   > ```

   the engine will scan one partition only?
2. issue 1 must happen without changing the indexes. I mean, **without** making back references in them, because it will be too much RAM consuming. So, this must not happen:

   > ```
   > KEY `index1` (`id_1`,`id_2`),
   > KEY `index1` (`id_2`,`id_1`),
   > ```
3. Am I thinking in a wrong direction? How would you solve this issue with Amazon RDS 7.5 GB RAM instance ?

feel free to edit this question, to make it more possible to be answered, thanks

reference to [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25246638/)

Comment: What is the primary key of the table?

Comment: Consider also using TokuDB engine that offers multiple clustered indexes. Your case seems ideal for that engine. You could have 2 clustered indexes on the table, one using `id1` and the other `id2`.

Comment: @ypercube primary key is auto_increment id, but i can change it. both of these two ids are unique but i am not using uniqueness on them currently

Comment: @ypercube I don't familiar with TokuDB, I will read about it later, thanks. But currently it must be amazon RDS only. any other suggestions?

Comment: Both answers below are good, but let's be clear: the answer is no, you cannot partition a single table by two different keys. Can I separate my jellybeans by color and also by size? No -- at best you can do subpartitioning for the second condition. But that won't allow you to search only one partition when you search for jellybeans by size.

Comment: @BillKarwin thanks for this clarification. it was basically the answer i was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had written an interesting alternative of implementing your own manual hash indexes for your table, and then I made maths and realised your constraints:

Having into memory 3 bigints will cost you `500*10^6*(8*8*8)/(1024*1024*1024) = 11.17GB` that you do not have. RDS is simply not adequate for you anymore, as it is not flexible enough to try some alternative engines -other than InnoDB (**you need an engine that works well with indexes on disk/clustering on several keys/hash indexes**)- and probably too costly to handle a large table like that.

You need either a higher-end instance or migrate to EC2 to deploy an alternative engine.

Best recommendation that I could give you for your current constraints (7GB ram, InnoDB):

Use your most frequently accessed keys as your primary key, partition by `RANGE` on that (lets call it `id_1`). Do not create any other secondary keys:

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
    id_1 bigint unsigned PRIMARY KEY,
    id_2 bigint unsigned not null,
    col3, col4 ... colN ...
) ENGINE=InnoDB
PARTITION BY RANGE (id_1) (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (n),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (m),
    ...
);
```

Create a separate table with (id_2, id_1):

```
CREATE TABLE `t1_id2_index` (
    id_2 bigint unsigned PRIMARY KEY,
    id_1 bigint unsigned not null,
) ENGINE=InnoDB
PARTITION BY RANGE (id_2) (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (n),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (m),
    ...
);
```

Obviously you will have to insert on this second table each time you insert on the first one. You may think this is worse, but it will not be *that bad* as you are getting rid of huge merging processes of the secondary keys and minimising memory usage (which is your goal, afterwards).

This will only access 1 partition on access by `id_1` and 2 partitions (one on each separate table) on access through id_2:

```
SELECT * FROM `t1` WHERE id_1 = 123;
-- or
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN t1.* 
FROM `t1_id2_index` 
JOIN `t1`
ON t1_id2_index.id_2 = 456 
   and 
   t1.id_1 = t2.id_1;
```

If your most frequent accesses are on the latest partitions, you will get the desired improvements -make sure you partition with that in mind. You can check partition pruning by using EXPLAIN PARTITIONS. Of course, if access patterns are completely random, you will not get any advantage. The goal is to maintain everything on disk except for a small set of primary keys for both id_1 and id_2 and selected rows.

You may want to minimise read ahead caching and tune `innodb_old_blocks_pct` and `innodb_old_blocks_time` for more effective caching/eviction on the buffer pool. I hope you are also using SSDs.

This is not beautiful, but please refer to my initial suggestion of migrating away from SAAS for custom requirements.

Comment: thanks for the help! I will accept this answer because of given arguments related to AWS and providing a possible new tables structure **including** PARTITION BY statements

Answer (score 0):

MySQL partitioning is handled as follows:

- MyISAM : Two file handles per partition (`.MYD`,`.MYI`)
- InnoDB : One file handle per partition (`.ibd`)
- Subpartitions simply create separate files, possibly multiplying the partitions

What you are trying to achieve can only be accomplished with a simply change

Create a column called `part` which forms a partition

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
    id_1 bigint unsigned not null,
    id_2 bigint unsigned not null,
    col3, col4 ... colN ...
    part int unsigned not null,
    KEY `index1` (`id_1`),
    KEY `index2` (`id_2`),
    KEY `index3` (part,`id_1`),
    KEY `index4` (part,`id_2`),
    ...
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

If you know all the keys that belong to a partition, just INSERT them.

```
INSERT INTO t1 (part,...) VALUES (127,...)
```

Also note that I made indexed to help the Query Optimizer choose the partition. Thus, your queries may look something like

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE part = 127;
```

You can isolate 123 with

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE part = 127 and id_1 = 123;
```

I have discussed this use of indexes on partitions before : [MySQL Read Speed and Partitioning on Separate Drives](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41205/mysql-read-speed-and-partitioning-on-separate-drives/41327#41327)

Without the compound indexes having part key, this would make mysqld scan all partitions.

If you are willing, you have a lot of work ahead of you to reorganize the table.

Comment: hi. May i ask from you to add the 'partition by' expression in the create statement in the answer? Thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: What is the part field? How should i calculate it? Based on what?